# What's the meaning of "at least as important are ..." in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Changes in the geometric properties of the joint with wear occur slowly for a lower pair. **At least as important are** the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit.

I don't understand the last sentence.

Comment: "At least as important" points out that the relative motions that the joints permit are, at minimum, equally important or more important than the changes in the geometric properties.

Comment: For future reference, please include more details, like where you found this and what you think it means. This will help keep your question open. See [_Details, Please_](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Changes in the geometric properties of the joint with wear occur slowly for a lower pair. *Just as important* are the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit. *Of the same importance* are the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit. Note that, for me, personally, I would also infer, "Just as important, *if not, more important*, are the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, "at least as important as" compares:

- changes (in the geometric properties...)

with

- (simple) geometries.

---

The meaning is that the geometries:

- have the same importance as the changes;

or:

- have more importance than the changes;

but not:

- have less importance than the changes.

---

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-least)

> **at least** = as much as, or more than, a number or amount:
>
> - It will cost **at least** $100.
> - It will be £200 **at** the very **least**.
> - You'll have to wait **at least** an hour.

and:

Also from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as)

> **As … as** = We use *as + adjective/adverb + as* to make comparisons when the things we are comparing are equal in some way:
>
> - The world’s biggest bull is **as** big **as** a small elephant.
> - The weather this summer is **as** bad **as** last year. It hasn’t stopped raining for weeks.
> - You have to unwrap it **as** carefully **as** you can. It’s quite fragile.

Answer (score 0):

> **Changes** in the geometric properties of the joint with wear **occur slowly** for a lower pair. **At least as important** are the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit.

There is missing information in this passage for us to explain *At least as important*.

*At least as important* in the second sentence tells us there is something else the importance of which is being compared with that of *the simple geometries of the relative motions that these joints permit*.

No such mentions on **importance** are in the first sentence, which is mainly a statement on the speed of the changes.

What is missing could be something like

> It is **important** to maintain the geometric properties of the joints.  Fortunately, [followed by sentence 1]